# Is there a maximum ordinal associated to a totally ordered set?

Tags: cardinals, ordinals, well-orders

Let $R$ be a totally ordered set. We can construct a well-ordered cofinal set $S \subset R$ by transfinite induction and the axiom of choice. (Choose an element from $R$ as the base case; then if we've chosen elements $s_i$ for all ordinals $i < \lambda$, if 
$$R_\lambda = \{ r \in R \; : \; r > s_i \textrm{ for all } i \}$$
is nonempty, pick $s_\lambda \in R_\lambda$. If $R_\lambda$ is empty, we're done.)

Here's my question. Can we, perhaps given some data about $R$ such as its cardinality, put an upper bound on the ordinal corresponding to $S$? Or is it possible for well-ordered cofinal subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, say, to have arbitrarily high ordinality?

Comment: I assume that last $R$ should be a normal  $R$ not a $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Well, you cannot have an ordinal of size $|R|^+$, obviously. On the other hand, $R $ itself could be well-ordered so, without knowing more about this ordering, no better bound can be suggested ($R $ could be any ordinal of size $|R|$). Additional information may tell us more. For instance, regardless of how big $|\mathbb R|$ is, only countable ordinals embed into $\mathbb R $, and it is a good exercise to see that any countable limit ordinal has a copy cofinal in $\mathbb R $.

Comment: In the displayed definition of $R_\lambda$, Should the condition "for all $i$ " be "for all $i<\lambda$ "? Otherwise, where is the reference to $\lambda$ in the definition?

Answer (score 1):

You trivially get that the ordinality is lower then the cardinality (and you can realize that bound by just taking the cardinal), but you can also get (from an ordinal view) very big differences. (I'm assuming AC for all of this answer).

Consider that the size of the Reals may be a weakly inaccessible (i.e. big). The reals are totally ordered, but the largest well ordered subset has ordinality strictly smaller then $\omega_1$. This follows since the rationals are dense and so if you had a well ordered subset of size $\omega_1$ it would have a countable cofinal subset.

I can't quickly see if you can get past the $2^\kappa$ boundary though.

Edit: I think there is actually almost certainly an upper bound of distance in terms of the beth function. This follows from some topological considerations I believe. I will check Juhasz when I get home.

Comment: What is the $\kappa$ that suddenly pops in in the third paragraph? And what is it that you're trying to get past "the $2^\kappa$ boundary"?

Comment: @bof It's badly written. I was wondering if you can get largest well ordered subset of size $\kappa$ in a total order strictly bigger than $2^\kappa$. I am strongly convinced there is a an upper bound to the beth size of  a total order whose biggest well ordered subset is $\kappa$

Comment: If the total order is a reverse well-ordering then every well-ordered subset is finite.

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of the fact that, if every well-ordered subset *and* every reverse well-ordered subset of your totally ordered set $S$ has cardinality at most $\kappa,$ then $S$ has cardinality at most $2^\kappa$. This follows from the Erdős–Rado theorem, if I remember right.